# Why doesn't Polymer insert the content?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to understand the Web Components, so I want to create a web component that would "wrap" a `select` tag into the [select2.](http://select2.github.io/)

Here's my main HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Web components</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/select2-select.html"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <select2-select>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
      </select2-select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"></link>

<polymer-element name="select2-select">
  <template>
    <select id="main">
      <content></content>
    </select>
  </template>
  <script>Polymer({});</script>
</polymer-element>
```

The problem is, the `option` tags aren't being inserted in the shadow DOM:

[image: dom-example]

What am I doing wrong? I'm running Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04.2, if it's anyhow relevant.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of Polymer do you use?

Comment: I use Polymer 0.5.6.

Comment: I suggest using 0.9 already, since 0.5 will probably not receive any major new features any longer, only bug fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that happens, the easiest way around it is to use attributes. I've amended your original script to make it work.

Main html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Web components</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/select2-select.html"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <select2-select options='[
      {"value":"1","text":"1"},
      {"value":"2","text":"2"},
      {"value":"3","text":"3"},
      {"value":"4","text":"4"}
      ]'></select2-select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="select2-select" attributes="options">
  <template>
    <select id="main">
        <template repeat="{{option in options}}">
        <option value={{option.value}}>{{option.text}}</option>
        </template>
    </select>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('select2-select', {
        publish: {
            options: {},
        }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can think of is that `JQuery` & `Select2` are not accessible to the element because you have added them to the global scope. As per [The Golden Standard](https://github.com/webcomponents/gold-standard/wiki) Expressed Dependencies section Web Components should be responsible for their own dependencies.

The other thing to look at is that some HTML elements will only render inside other specific elements. For example - If I add `option` tags to `div`, they will not render unless they are wrapped in a `select` tag.

Comment: 1. I've not even started to add jQuery or Select2, because I couldn't make `<content>` work properly.
2. While "weird" elements may not be shown correctly, they still will be present in DOM, like [here](http://i.imgur.com/Zv1IuXy.png)